# how to add custom button on product category page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i have create custom button("live preview")on product page using following code

```
<?php 
    if($_product->getCustom_button()){ //yes or no button
?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?>" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_url() ;?>')"><span><span><i class="icon-desktop"></i><?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?></span></span></button>
<?php } ?>
```

how i can add this button on product category page button name is "live preview"
i am using magento

[image: image of custom button]

Comment: Please let me know your code using on category page for this button

Answer (score 1):

please use this code in you product display loop in list.phtml

```
<?php 
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); 
    if($product->getCustomButton()){ //yes or no button
?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $product->getCustomButtonName() ;?>" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $product->getCustomButtonUrl() ;?>')"><span><span><i class="icon-desktop"></i><?php echo $product->getCustomButtonName() ;?></span></span></button>
<?php } ?>
```